# Find max value in a group based on various criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this table:

| Level | Code | Hours |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Code1 | 1000 |
| 2 | Code1 | 134 |
| 3 | Code1 | 1100 |
| 3 | Code1 | 1300 |
| 4 | Code1 | 234 |
| 4 | Code1 | 1234 |
| 5 | Code1 | 34 |
| 6 | Code1 | 12 |
| 1 | Code2 | 300 |
| 2 | Code2 | 400 |
| 5 | Code2 | 500 |
| 5 | Code2 | 550 |
| 5 | Code2 | 700 |
| 6 | Code2 | 600 |
| 1 | Code3 | 100 |
| 2 | Code3 | 350 |
| 1 | Code4 | 7200 |
| 5 | Code4 | 150 |

If there are records for Level 3 and/or 4 then I need the max value between these level for the code. If level 3 and 4 are not present for the code then get max value of level 5 and/or 6. If neither of level 3, 4, 5 and 6 are present then the query should return max value of level 1 and/or 2.

So the result of above table should be like:

| Level | Code | Hours |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | Code1 | 1300 |
| 5 | Code2 | 700 |
| 2 | Code3 | 350 |
| 5 | Code4 | 150 |

I have tried this:

```
SELECT * INTO #tempMaxTimeEntryData FROM
(SELECT LEVEL, CODE, HOURS = MAX(HOURS) FROM tempTimeEntryData 
 GROUP BY LEVEL, CODE) maxtemp

SELECT CODE, HOURS FROM #tempMaxTimeEntryData GROUP BY CODE
HAVING MAX(HOURS) = 
(SELECT HOURS= MAX(HOURS),CODE FROM #tempMaxTimeEntryData 
 WHERE 1 = (CASE WHEN LEVEL IN (3.0,4.0) THEN 1
               WHEN LEVEL NOT IN (3.0,4.0) AND LEVEL IN (5.0,6.0) THEN 1
               WHEN LEVEL NOT IN (3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0) AND LEVEL IN (1.0,2.0) THEN 1
               END) GROUP BY CODE)
```

This is returning wrong data for Code4. Instead of Level 5, it is returning below:

| Level | Code | Hours |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Code4 | 7200 |

New data:

| Employee | Level | Code | Hours |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Danilo | 2 | Code1 | 1080 |
| Akash | 1 | Code2 | 82.7 |
| Shradha | 2 | Code2 | 838.7 |
| Shalini | 3 | Code2 | 813.6 |
| Priyanka | 3.5 | Code2 | 2684.4 |
| Gagan | 4 | Code2 | 3240 |
| Manu | 5 | Code2 | 870 |
| Akash | 1 | Code3 | 604.2 |
| Shradha | 2 | Code3 | 3372 |
| Manu | 5 | Code3 | 1230 |
| Ashu | 6 | Code3 | 2270 |
| Akash | 1 | Code4 | 448.8 |
| Shradha | 2 | Code4 | 2375.4 |
| Shalini | 3 | Code4 | 2811 |
| Priyanka | 3 | Code4 | 2811 |
| Ritu | 4 | Code4 | 85.2 |
| Praveen | 5 | Code4 | 67.2 |
| Rakesh | 1 | Code5 | 47580 |
| Sampath | 5 | Code5 | 339 |

Output should be:

| Employee | Level | Code | Hours |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Danilo | 2 | Code1 | 1080 |
| Gagan | 4 | Code2 | 3240 |
| Ashu | 6 | Code3 | 2270 |
| Priyanka | 3 | Code4 | 2811 |
| Sampath | 5 | Code5 | 339 |

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ROW_NUMBER` window function, that will partition the `Code` column and order on the `Level` field (according to your priority requirement of [3,4] > [5,6] > [1,2]) and on the `Hours` descending.

Once you have the max amount of hours filtered out with your requirement, you can select for each row, which `Hours` field value corresponds to the extracted maximum value.

```
SELECT Employee,
       Level,
       Code,
       Hours
FROM (SELECT tab.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
                 PARTITION BY Code
                 ORDER BY CASE WHEN Level < 3 THEN 2
                               WHEN Level > 4 THEN 1
                               ELSE                0 END, 
                          Hours DESC        ) AS HoursOrder
      FROM tab)   ordered_hours
WHERE HoursOrder = 1
```

Try it [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=33d4c6a59f9255b1fa0ccbc575ff1465).

Comment: Thank you for the response @lemon. This was helpful! Further, I need a help to get the values by employee name. Say: there are two employees with level 3 and have same number of hours. Then it should return the record based on alphabetical order.

Comment: You can add an `ORDER BY` clause, after the `WHERE` clause, like this `ORDER BY Code, Level, Hours, EmployeeName`. @user2572573

Comment: Hi lemon, thank you for your help. The above query is not giving expected result in SQL Server.

Comment: Testing is provided only for the data you made available in your post. If you provide data about employee names, I can update the answer with a tested solution. @user2572573

Comment: Hi lemon, I have added the test data and expected output. Can you please have a look and help? I am using SQL Server for writing the query.

Comment: Updated my answer @user2572573. Now it should work for employee names too.

Comment: I was looking at your earlier MySQL query with the `max(X) over (order by ...)` which apparently evaluates to null after the first row. Do you know where that behavior is documented? I can't find it anywhere.

Comment: I'm curious about the behavior and wanted to learn more about it.

Comment: Try it here: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nSJTyxEX5ExhS9v3tnZwQ9/0, works for sql-server too. This contains the former shared data of this post and worked fine for that, as from the first comment of this thread. Problem comes when there is more than one employee with the same max value and a field like the employee name, as in the current state of the input.

Comment: I'm aware that your query worked. It's the behavior of `max()` returning null that has me investigating deeper: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nSJTyxEX5ExhS9v3tnZwQ9/0

Comment: Also, adding a tying row (#26) would break it: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nSJTyxEX5ExhS9v3tnZwQ9/0 But again I'm not trying to prove you did anything wrong. I'm just exploring the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You just want to apply an order to the rows (per code) and then pick out the ones at the top:

```
WITH Data as (
    SELECT Code, Level, Hours,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY Code ORDER BY
                CASE WHEN Level IN (3, 4) THEN 1
                     WHEN Level IN (5, 6) THEN 2
                     WHEN Level IN (1, 2) THEN 3 END,
                Hours DESC
                --, Employee
        ) AS rn
    FROM tab
)
SELECT * FROM DATA WHERE rn = 1;
```